# Creating new instance of class inside enum constructor when enum is in the class

Tags: java, enums

Initially I thought I would have a chicken and egg problem here, but exploring this in a unit test doesn't indicate any problems.  I want to understand what is going on here.  I would have thought that since enums are static and final the `MyEnum` constructor would run when the JVM loads `MyClass`.  However in my test it prints "getValue" before "MyEnum constructor".

```
MyClass {

   private enum MyEnum {
       VALUE;

       MyEnum() {
          System.out.println("MyEnum constructor");
          MyClass clazz = new MyClass(); 
       }
   }

   public MyEnum getValue() {
      System.out.println("getValue");
      return MyEnum.VALUE;
   }

}

public class MyClassTest {

    @Test
    public void testStuff() {
        MyClass clazz = new MyClass();
        clazz.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you think _static initialization time_ is?

Comment: Potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296547/execution-order-of-enum-in-java

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818026/force-initialization-of-an-enumerated-type-in-java

Comment: I meant when the class is loaded.  I don't think this is a duplicate, this has a private enum inside of a class whereas the proposed dupe does not.

Comment: The location of the `MyEnum` type is not important. It will be initialized, like any class, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/when-does-static-class-initialization-happen, ie. _a non-constant static field is used_. That field is the enum constant.

Comment: My example shows that the the print in the `getValue` method is firing BEFORE the enum constructor, which seems opposite of what your link says

Comment: The `MyEnum.VALUE` enum constant is accessed inside `getValue` after the print. So the `MyEnum` class is only initialized _then_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that a class/interface/enum/annotation is nested within another class does not affect when its initialization will occur.

The rules for initialization apply regardless. They are defined in the JLS [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - **A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).**

The JLS also [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) the following about `enum` types

> An enum declaration specifies a new enum type, **a special kind of class type**.

And [about its members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3), it says

> For each enum constant c declared in the body of the declaration of `E`,
>   `E` has an implicitly declared `public static final` field of type `E` that
>   has the same name as `c`. The field has a variable initializer which
>   instantiates `E` and passes any arguments of `c` to the constructor chosen
>   for `E`. The field has the same annotations as `c` (if any).

Put all this together and you get an explanation for the behavior you see.

Your code instantiates `MyClass`, then invokes its `getValue()` method. `getValue()` prints something to standard out and then tries to access a static field declared by `MyEnum`. This triggers initialization of the enum type, which initializes the `public static static VALUE` field, which invokes the corresponding `MyEnum` construct that again prints to standard out.