# Better Map Constructor

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

Is there a more streamlined way to do the following?

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("a", "apple");
map.put("b", "bear");
map.put("c", "cat");
```

I'm looking for something closer to this.

```
 Map<String, String> map = MapBuilder.build("a", "apple", "b", "bear", "c", "cat");
```

Comment: are the keys/values hardcoded like that?  if so, why not something like loading a json string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/json-to-map

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a best practice for writing maps literal style in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798083/is-there-a-best-practice-for-writing-maps-literal-style-in-java), and [initialize java HashSet values by construction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041778/initialize-java-hashset-values-by-construction)

Comment: @David: That is a great for constants. Especially for me because I use JSON frequently and often have the methods available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there isn't, but I wrote a method to do exactly this, inspired by Objective-C NSDictionary class:

```
public static Map<String, Object> mapWithKeysAndObjects(Object... objects) {

    if (objects.length % 2 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The array has to be of an even size - size is "
                        + objects.length);
    }

    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    for (int x = 0; x < objects.length; x+=2) {
      values.put((String) objects[x], objects[x + 1]);
    }

    return values;

}
```

Comment: This breaks Java generics type safety.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to reinvent ImmutableMap.of(...) in google's collection

Comment: I would reinvent to avoid adding **yet another unnecessary library full of unnecessary classes** when all i want is a single method.

Comment: Great idea @Robert, added it now.

Comment: Maurício, looking at number of iterations in your code, you had saved some time and bugs by using a proven library. Besides, you may find it actually useful and it would help toy write a cleaner and safer code.

Comment: Eugene, that's a matter of opinion, I don't find it useful to add a library instead of typing 15 lines of code.

Comment: Guava is bloated v18 adds 2.5MB jar file (without sources), if you are going to use 1% of it, I'd rather use custom sollutions like this one for faster compile/deploy times.

Answer (score 16):

There's always [double-brace initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
    put("a", "apple"); put("b", "bear"); put("c", "cat");}};
```

There are problems with this approach. It returns an anonymous inner class extending HashMap, not a HashMap. If you need to serialize the map then know that [serialization of inner classes is discouraged](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539).

Comment: Most likely caveat is that will not be Serializable.

Comment: +1. interesting, I did not see that before. Question is if it makes life really easier :-)

Comment: This is generally not a good idea for any kind of production code. It also creates anonymous class every time.

Comment: @George: it's not that it isn't Serializable, it's that a compiler warning complains it doesn't have a serialUID.

Comment: @Nathan, I did not know you could serialize anonymous subclasses, but even then, I wouldn't recommend it. *["Serialization of inner classes (i.e., nested classes that are not static member classes), including local and **anonymous classes**, is strongly discouraged for several reasons."](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539)*

Comment: The deserialized map will have the original values for these keys, even if changed later (before serializing).

Answer (score 9):

You could use [ImmutableMap.Builder](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html) from Google collections library.

Answer (score 3):

**Java 9** adds `Map.of`, such as:

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("a", "apple", "b", "bear", "c", "cat");
```

Up to 10 entries are supported. For more entries you can use the overload taking Entry:

```
Map<String, String> map 
    = Map.ofEntries
        (Map.entry("a", "apple")
        , Map.entry("b", "bear")
        , Map.entry("c", "cat"));
```

Note that these methods do not return a HashMap. It returns an optimized immutable map.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use *double brace initialization*:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("foo", "bar");
    put("baz", "qux");
}}
```

But bear in mind this might not be efficient according to [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization).

Comment: whoever came up with the name 'double brace initialization' should be shot. This is a valid declaration of an anonymous class combined with a non-static initializer block.