# Key-value collection with convenient notation

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I am looking for a Map-like collection that would allow me to create new object in a PHP/Python/JavaScript way:

```
var foo = new Foo({'foo': 'bar'})
```

The closest I have in Java is HashMap:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("test", "one two");
parameters.put("foo", "bar");
```

This is too verbose for my purpose. I would like to write down and handle over key-value pairs in an easier way.

I welcome any suggestions - creating own type of collection, creating own factory for a Map object etc. I just want to axe number of characters needed to write down to create such a collection.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833925/better-map-constructor/6833946#6833946

Comment: Here you go: http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/374/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way I've seen, when sticking to the base JDK, is to just use anonymous initializers:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
  put("test", "one two");
  put("foo", "bar");
}};
```

You can also take a look at the Guava ImmutableMap builder: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html

If you want to get a little far out there you could write a parser for something like JSON (or just JSON itself and a JSON library) and then write the Map as a string.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go with the double brace trick, but the JSON suggestion is also nice.

Answer (score 3):

You have the (not very well-known) [double brace initialization trick](http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/java/double-brace-initialization/):

```
Map<String, String> Map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
      put("test", "one two");
      put("foo", "bar");
}};
```

With java 7 diamond operator this is even more succinct, see:

```
Map<String, String> Map = new HashMap<>() {{
      put("test", "one two");
      put("foo", "bar");
}};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization