# How can I check if an element exists in a Set of items?

Tags: java, collections

In an `if` statement in Java how can I check whether an object exists in a set of items. E.g.
In this scenario i need to validate that the fruit will be an apple, orange or banana.

```
if (fruitname in ["APPLE", "ORANGES", "GRAPES"]) {
    //Do something
}
```

It's a very trivial thing but I couldn't figure out a short and concise way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
static final List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList("APPLE", "ORANGES", "GRAPES");

if (fruits.contains(fruitname))
```

If your list was much larger, a set would be more efficient.

```
static final Set<String> fruits = new HashSet<String>(
       Arrays.asList("APPLE", "ORANGES", "GRAPES", /*many more*/));
```

Comment: Might as well make it a `Set`. Seems more appropriate.

Comment: @wds There isn't really an Arrays.asSet method, and if this is the only use for the collection the extra conversion (to Set) step wouldn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: Not for a list with three entries.  For more entries it might be worth it.

Comment: I'm guessing having to hash the key actually takes longer than doing a lookup in a table of a few dozen elements. Still, `Set` is the right type for the job, even if the particular implementation might not be.

Comment: @wds, true, for a small number of entries, it hardly matters which is faster.  You can scan a List of 100K entries in about a milli-second which might be fast enough.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If the list is not a collection of Strings, lets say just a custom object, do we need to override equal method?

Comment: @WowBow It depends on the class, however you may need to override equals/hashCode or compareTo depending on the collection used.

Answer (score 10):

for completeness using google-collections/guava:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

static final Set<String> fruit = Sets.newHashSet("APPLE", "ORANGES", "GRAPES");

if (fruit.contains(fruitname))
```

or using the plane old jdk classes:

```
static final Set<String> fruit = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("APPLE", "ORANGES", "GRAPES"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Is [Arrays.binarySearch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29) what you are looking for?

```
String [] fruits = new String[]{"APPLE", "ORANGES", "GRAPES"};
Arrays.sort(fruits); // binarySearch requires that the array is sorted

if (Arrays.binarySearch(fruits), fruitname) >= 0) {
  // found!
}
```

And of course the trusted [Apache Commons ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
if (ArrayUtils.contains(new String[]{"APPLE", "ORANGES", "GRAPES"}, fruitname){
  // found
}
```

I knew there would be something in Apache Commons :)

Comment: binary search assumes the array is sorted, I remember O coming after G ;)

Comment: I noticed :) So I added a sort. I like your solution better though (that's the upvote:)

Comment: @peter: there's an Array.sort() in there ;)

Comment: k thx for the info! sorry peter I upvoted your comment then ;)

Comment: `Arrays.sort` is a void method, so this doesn't really compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Set`, `List`, `Map` of fruits which all have the same parent: `Collection`, you can try this example.

```
String fruitName = "Orange";
Collection<String> fruits = ... // set of fruits
if (fruits.contains(fruitName)) {
    ...
}
```

(For Java 8/9/10 ways of creating literal `Set` please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37406054/2693875).)

Be careful with case sensitivity (Orange != orange).