# multiply if statements vs. collection.contains

Tags: java, if-statement, collections

Which way better?

```
if ("Pablo".equals(name) || "Marko".equals(name) || .. );
```

or

```
if (Sets.newHashSet("Pablo", "Marko", ..).contains(name));
```

Interest about memory using, performance, readabilty

Comment: We can use switch instead of these..

Comment: What is your real world problem where this even matters?  I would assume that the compiler is smart enough to optimize the first case as much as it can.

Comment: [You can measure it yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant), and [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689334/how-can-i-check-if-an-element-exists-in-a-set-of-items), but... not too bad.

Comment: either way, your first statement would be better written as: if ( "Pablo".equals(name) || "Marko".equals(name) || ... )

Comment: For constant list of value, I like to use a `Collection` to check. But I only create one instance. I don't create a `Set` live. I feel this is a bit more readable but with correct method, this could be done the first way to.

Comment: I'd say, factor it out to a function with a sensible name. Much more readable than some arbitrary expression, and you can always fiddle with the implementation later (if you really must).

Comment: Please define, how you measure. What is `good`? What is `better`?

Comment: @Stultuske thx for comment, i'm know this. just make quick example for showing idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The if statement will take linear time (O(n)), since it has `n` conditions to evaluate at the worst case.

The `Set.contains` variant will take linear time to construct the `Set` (adding `n` elements), but only constant time to search the `Set` for a specific value.

Therefore, if you run this condition multiple times (for the same set of values), 
creating the `Set` once and reusing it multiple times will be more efficient than running the if statement multiple times.

Comment: It's type of condition to listener, so i think best would be make static Set with values and use it in if with .contains?