# Instantiate a map in a more concise manner in Java

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hashmap, instantiation

Is there any shorter way of doing this?

```
Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
values.put("A", 1);
values.put("E", 1);
values.put("D", 2);
values.put("R", 2);
values.put("B", 3);
values.put("M", 3);
values.put("V", 4);
values.put("Y", 4);
values.put("J", 8);
values.put("X", 8);
```

With arrays in Java you can do this for example

```
int[] temp = {1,2};
```

instead of

```
int[] temp = new int[2]
temp[0] = 1;
temp[1] = 2;
```

I am looking to something similar with the Map above.
Is that possible?

Thanks for the help, as always :)

Comment: have you looked at the methods present in HashMap ??.. If you are using eclipse, ctrl+space will give you your answer.

Comment: I don't know what to look for in the HashMap API. Could you point me into the right direction?
and I am not using eclipse @TheLostMind

Comment: well..If you look at the HashMap API, you wont find any method that would help you..  I would look at Peter's answer... use a loop if necessary...

Answer (score 4):

You could try this, but you have to be careful:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String, Integer>()
{
    {
        put("A", 1);
        put("E", 1);
        put("D", 2);
        put("R", 2);
        put("B", 3);
        put("M", 3);
        put("V", 4);
        put("Y", 4);
        put("J", 8);
        put("X", 8);
    }
};
```

Read more about [Double Brace Initialization here](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization).

Comment: That's what I'd do in C/C++

Answer (score 3):

There is no easier way using Java only, but if you use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you could do this:

```
  Map<String, Integer> values = 
     ImmutableMap.<String, Integer> builder().put("A", 1).put("E", 1).put("D", 2).build();
```

See also:

- [How can I initialise a static Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-to-initialise-a-static-map-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no direct way of doing this.

You need to initialize the map as you suggested.

```
Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
values.put("A", 1);
values.put("E", 1);
values.put("D", 2);
values.put("R", 2);
values.put("B", 3);
values.put("M", 3);
values.put("V", 4);
values.put("Y", 4);
values.put("J", 8);
values.put("X", 8);
```

If there's any pattern in these values, you can simplify that to using a loop.

An alternative is to use HashMapBuilder.

See also here.

[How to directly initialize a HashMap (in a literal way)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802483/how-to-directly-initialize-a-hashmap-in-a-literal-way)

Another alternative is to use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). They have a method for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that you know the combination of keys and values, you can do like this, but its a kind of hack :

```
String[] keys = {"A", "B", "C"};
int[] values = {1, 2, 3};

Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  myMap.put(keys[i], values[i]);
}
```

But you have to be very careful, most importantly that both your arrays should be of same length.

Comment: Please check your code. Is it error free??