# Java HashMap - Is it necessary to use .put() for each set?

Tags: java, hashmap

Imagine the following scenario. You have a set of values which are already accessible and known. You have to put them into a HashMap for reasons.

Code example:

```
String a = "a";
Strinb b = "b";
...
HashMap map = new HashMap(5);
map.put("a", a);
map.put("b", b);
...
```

Is it really necessary to do it like this? I can't believe that there is not a constructor which let you put in your values from scratch.

I'm talking about something like this:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap(<"a", a>, <"b", b>, ...);
```

Or even something like this:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap(5);
HashMap.putBunchOfStuff("a", a, "b", b, ...);
```

Edit: My intention was to ask if there is a method but *more importantly*, **if the answer is "no", why there isn't such a constructor/method.**

Comment: Idk if Java8 has some new trickery or not.  But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialize-a-static-map) question was asked a few years ago and the consensus was no. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802483/how-to-directly-initialize-a-hashmap-in-a-literal-way)

Comment: you cannot do like this... But you can add another Map into this by using putAll(Map(K,v));

Comment: I wonder if it is accessible from the beginning, why don't you use `enums`, or if you don't like duplication for key and value, then why isn't it `Set`, or you can create 'MyHashMap' where you define `put(Object o)`

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary It's a little more complicated in the actual problem. This was just pseudo code.

Comment: @OddDev You should always provide code as close to the actual code as possible. Otherwise you might be solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @Kayaman you should calm down. ;) This code is simplified yes, but there are other smart people besides you who are able to simplify a code without loosing the adaption.

Comment: @OddDev I am perfectly calm, but the description you gave below ("I have to get stuff out of a resultset into hasmaps stored in an array") doesn't reflect the extremely simple example you gave above.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, *collection literals* were a [proposal for Project Coin](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001193.html) in Java 7 (and Java 8), but **it never made it into the final product**, aka it is not a feature of Java.

The proposition was this

```
Here’s how it would look with map literals:


    final Map<Integer, String> platonicSolids = { 
          4 : "tetrahedron",
          6 : "cube", 
          8 : "octahedron", 
          12 : "dodecahedron", 
          20 : "icosahedron"
    };


Here is the empty map literal, which has a slightly irregular syntax to make
it differ from the empty set:


    Map<String, Integer> noJokeHere = { : };
```

*BUT it never happened*, so unfortunately that doesn't work. So unless you write your own magic builder or fancy lambda like [on this site of Per-Åke Minborg](http://minborgsjavapot.blogspot.hu/2014/12/java-8-initializing-maps-in-smartest-way.html), you're on your own. The following from the site should work, though (in Java 8).

```
//copy paste from linked site
Map<Integer, String> map = Stream.of(
            new SimpleEntry<>(0, "zero"),
            new SimpleEntry<>(1, "one"),
            //...
            new SimpleEntry<>(11, "eleven"),
            new SimpleEntry<>(12, "twelve"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap((e) -> e.getKey(), (e) -> e.getValue()));
```

And the simplified version, also from the [site](http://minborgsjavapot.blogspot.hu/2014/12/java-8-initializing-maps-in-smartest-way.html):

```
//copy paste from linked site
public static <K, V> Map.Entry<K, V> entry(K key, V value) {
    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value);
}

public static <K, U> Collector<Map.Entry<K, U>, ?, Map<K, U>> entriesToMap() {
    return Collectors.toMap((e) -> e.getKey(), (e) -> e.getValue());
}

Map<Integer, String> map = Stream.of(
            entry(0, "zero"),
            //...
            entry(12, "twelve"))
            .collect(entriesToMap());
```

Collection literals weren't introduced because of [these points](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2014-March/011938.html):

- The "simple" version of this feature (sets, lists, maps only) is not 
  very satisfying or popular; the "extensible" version of this feature is 
  open-ended, messy, and virtually guaranteed to way overrun its design 
  budget;
- The library-based version gives us X% of the benefit for 1% of the 
  cost, where X >> 1;
- Value types are coming, and the "what would this feature look like" 
  in a world with value types may well be quite different than in a world 
  without, suggesting it would be questionable to try and do this work 
  before value types;
- We are better off focusing our language-design bandwidth on 
  addressing more the foundational issues underlying a library-based 
  version (including: more efficient varargs, array constants in the 
  constant pool, immutable arrays, and support for caching (and reclaiming 
  under pressure) intermediate immutable results).

[By Brian Goetz from Oracle](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2014-March/011938.html)

Comment: ...you mean the second one, right? The first one was a proposition. That never happened.

Comment: No, I was talking about the answer in general. Very nice, clear information and exactly the INFO I was looking for. It wasn't my intention to grab a code snippet.

Comment: ah, in that case, I'm glad you found it helpful, and you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such constructor by default - you could use the double-brace idiom to `put` all values in the map on instantiation, but this still requires multiple put calls:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>() {{
    put("a", "val1");
    put("b", "val2");
    //etc.
}};
```

In reality you usually have large blocks of data you want to put into a map accessible from a stream or another collection, so it's trivial to loop over multiple `put` calls in this instance.

Guava has a `putAll()` on its `ImmutableMap.Builder`, enabling you to do something similar to this before instantiation. Other external libraries may have other similar behaviour, but fact is you'll have to resort to using external libraries.

Comment: Note: double-brace initialization creates an anonymous subclass which among other things keeps a strong reference to the outer instance (thus keeping it alive) if it's used in a non-static context.

Comment: @Radiodef This is true - I don't find it an ideal idiom at all (it's more an accident of obscure syntax than something designed for this use.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a pretty utility method to create maps using varargs.

Example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K, V> HashMap<K, V> newMap(Object... elems) {
    HashMap<K, V> m = new HashMap<K, V>();

    for (int i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 2) {
        m.put((K) elems[i], (V) elems[i + 1]);    
    }

    return m;
}

Map<String, Integer> m = newMap("k1", 1, "k2", 2);
```

**Beware:** This is not type safe and might result in a map with objects of the wrong types if you make a mistake when using it, throwing `ClassCastException` in unexpected places. This is called  [heap pollution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution). Example:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = newMap("k1", 1, "k2", "2");
int s = m.get("k2");  // ClassCastException!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that :

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(5){{
    put("a", "a");
    put("b", "b");
}};
```

But I don't know if u can use with local variable a and b.

Comment: Note: this creates an anonymous subclass which among other things keeps a strong reference to the outer instance (thus keeping it alive) if it's used in a non-static context.