# Literal declaration of HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, literals

In `JavaScript`, you can declare all the keys and value combinations for a `JSON` object in one go as follows...

```
var myJSON = {
    'key1' : 'value 1',
    'key2' : 'value 2',
    'key3' : 'value 3',
    'key4' : 'value 4',
    'key5' : 'value 5',
    'key6' : 'value 6'
};
```

I was wondering whether we can do something similar in `Java` for `HashMaps`.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(
    "Key 1", "Value 1",
    "Key 2", "Value 2",
    "Key 3", "Value 3"
);
```

Basically, I need this as a one time read only thing as Config for the other parts of my code. I searched and tried a few solutions, but was not able to make them work. Or is there a better approach that I can do?

Comment: @MarounMaroun That is not a duplicate. A static map is not equal to `Literal Declaration`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Thumbs up. Reopened.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Answered :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Disagree with this as well :-/

Comment: @suresh: it looks like a good duplicate to me. esp since your answer is the same as one of the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6802512/217324

Comment: @NathanHughes Yes. Agreed now :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Since the put method still invoking on the instance :) `myMap.put("a", "b");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though `{{` (double brace) is an anti pattern, something like this you can write

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
put("Key 1", "Value 1");
put("Key 2", "Value 2");
put("Key 3", "Value 3");    
}};
```

Edit :

If you are looking for a better way to put elements, iterate over your json and put key values in a loop.

Comment: @JordiCastilla or not! The map will hold a reference to the enclosing class  which may be undesirable...

Comment: just missing a quote in `"Value 3` .... ;)

Comment: @assylias my opinion... but this is the way OP is asking, I like more your example, yes, but OP is asking for a static way similar to JSon... and this is the way...

Comment: I did ask if there was a better solution at the end. I guess this is a solution, but it may be preferable to go with assylias' reply, yes? Basically, this is just a one time read only variable thing. I will not be manipulating it. So would prefer the most efficient method.

Comment: @ShahidThaika you can freely choose your answer :)

Comment: I meant to confirm this - This reply is the solution to my question, but from a programming standpoint, it may be better to code using assylias' reply.

In other words, choose this as an answer, but code using the other.

Comment: @ShahidThaika My answer will be different if you ask for `what is the best way to add elements`, My answer purely concentrated on `Literal declaration of HashMap in Java` :)

Comment: Can you add that too, then I will close by choosing this reply.

Comment: @ShahidThaika That will be adding in a loop. Updating that

Answer (score 3):

There is no concept of map literals in Java but you can easily write a utility method to achieve something similar. See [this implementation](https://bitbucket.org/assylias/bigblue-utils/src/master/src/main/java/com/assylias/bigblue/utils/Maps.java?at=master) for example. You can then initialise a map (using static imports):

```
Map<String, String> map = map("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2");
```

An alternative is to use the "double brace initialisation" syntax but it creates an anonymous inner class which is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Yes.. I don't like the double "{" solution.