# Constant Map for case selection in switch statement?

Tags: java, dictionary, switch-statement

Is there a way to define a constant `Map` for the use in a switch statement? All my trials with static Maps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialize-a-static-map), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802483/how-to-directly-initialize-a-hashmap-in-a-literal-way) and others were not successful. Why isn't the Map constant?

For the line `case (kws.get(KEYWORD_NAME)):` I always get `constant string expression required` error.

```
public class Demo {

  public static final String KEYWORD_NAME = "Name";
  public static final String KEYWORD_TYPE = "Type";

  private static final Map<String, String> kws = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
  new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put(KEYWORD_NAME, KEYWORD_NAME.toLowerCase());
    put(KEYWORD_TYPE, KEYWORD_TYPE.toLowerCase());
  }});

  public static void parse(String kw){
    switch(kw){
      case (kws.get(KEYWORD_NAME)):
        System.out.println("Test");
        break;
    default:
      System.out.println("Unknown");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `case` expressions must be *compile-time constants*. How do you expect the compiler to know what `kws.get(KEYWORD_NAME)` will do?

Comment: Every `switch` statement can be accomplished with a Map.  You could, for example, create a `Map<String, Runnable>`.  Java 8 method references make this fairly easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because the case labels in a switch statement must be either constant expressions or enumerators.

The reference to your Map is `final`, and your map is unmodifiable. But the latter is enforced at *run time*. The compiler does not treat the object as a constant.

From the [Java Language Specification, 14.11: The switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

```
SwitchLabel:
case ConstantExpression : 
case EnumConstantName : 
default :
```

Constant expressions can be composed only of primitive and String literals, certain operators without side-effects, constant variables, and a few other components that can be computed at compile-time. (A constant variable is a `final` variable of primitive or String type that's been initialized to a constant expression.) More detail is at [15.28: Constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your use case, but instead of using unmodifiable map you can use parametrized enum:

>> when:

```
public enum Demo {
     NAME("Name"),
     TYPE("Type"),
     NOT_SUPPORTED("");

    private String code;
    private static final Map<String, Demo> CODE_VALUE_MAP = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // -- static
    static {
        for (Demo demo : Demo.values()) {
            CODE_VALUE_MAP.put(demo.getCode(), demo );
        }
     }

   public static Demo forCode(@NotNull String code) {
        if (code!= null) {
            return CODE_VALUE_MAP.getOrDefault(code.toUpperCase(), NOT_SUPPORTED);
           }
           return NOT_SUPPORTED;
       }    
   }

   // -- constructor
   Demo(String code) {
       this.code= code;
   }

   // -- public methods
   public String getCode() {
       return code;
   }
}
```

>>Then:

```
...
public static void parse(String kw){
 Demo demo = Demo.forCode(kw);
 switch(demo){
  case NAME:
    System.out.println("Test");
    break;
default:
  System.out.println("Unknown");
}
...
```