# Java - pass key-value params into function with shortest syntax

Tags: java, syntax, syntactic-sugar

I want to pass list of key-values pairs into my function.

I can do this by following:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("param1", value1);
params.put("param2", value2);
foo(params);
```

But there are 4 lines of code. And my `foo` function will be called in many times in my code, so it becomes hard to read.

Can we decrease number of lines in this call?

1. Is there a way to write `foo([("param1", value1), ("param2", value2)])`?
2. Maybe Java standard classes have constructors to pass there several elements?
3. Or can we write some factory class, that will create HashMap in less lines of code?

Comment: You Can pass in a flat list and convert it to a map in your method.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Will it work below Java 8? Can you give a short example or link?

Comment: 1. [No collection literals](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2014-March/011938.html) for now. 2. [Probably soon](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269). 3. Sure. Should be pretty trivial?

Comment: @aioobe I am not sure why this question was reopened. The linked question has a lot of answers showing how to initialize a Map in a single line, using various libraries or tricks, which is what this question is asking. What about this other one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802483/how-to-directly-initialize-a-hashmap-in-a-literal-way?lq=1

Comment: I think what @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen is suggestion is that you do `Arrays.asList("param1", value1, "param2", value2)`.

Comment: @Tunaki, that's a much better question to refer to here imo.

Comment: @Tunaki The linked question shows an example of static map. I've looking at answers there for 15 minutes already, but can't find the appreciate answer.

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev, do you feel your question is properly answered by [How to directly initialize a HashMap (in a literal way)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802483/how-to-directly-initialize-a-hashmap-in-a-literal-way?lq=1)?

Comment: @aioobe Yes, that's was I've searched. But I couldn't find it while Googling, so maybe my title will help someone to find that.