# How to define hash map values in one line?

Tags: java

In Java, if we want to pass list of values to a method that can be achieved with `Arrays.asList(...)` method like -

`methodToCall("CA", Arrays.asList("John", "Bob", "Mike"));`

How can we achieve same for HashMap in one line like above?

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of() (and the overloaded versions)

Comment: Please, *please* don't think it's a good idea to use double-brace initialization (just in case anybody suggests it).

Comment: You mean like `put("A","B","C")`? How would you map keys and values, especially of different types?

Comment: Probably the better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialise-a-static-map?noredirect=1&lq=1 And yes, don't do the double-brace initializer trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization

Comment: Check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802483/how-to-directly-initialize-a-hashmap-in-a-literal-way. It's really what you're asking for.