# Java HashMap initialization?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, declaration, sonarlint

I already know how to initialize Java `HashMap` by using one of the following 2 ways

```
// way 1: apply generic type saftey
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

// way 2: general without apply generic type saftey
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap2 = new HashMap();
```

My problem
What is the best practice

According to **Eclipse Marker**

> Type safety: The expression of type HashMap needs unchecked conversion
>   to conform to HashMap

[image] 
So Its recommend to use

```
new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

But according to **Sonar Linter**

> Replace the type specification in this constructor call with the
>   diamond operator ("<>").

[image]
So Its recommend to use

```
new HashMap();
```

Which one is the best? Why?

Comment: Related question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialise-a-static-map

Comment: Related question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802483/how-to-directly-initialize-a-hashmap-in-a-literal-way

Comment: `new HashMap();` is not using the diamond operator. It should be `new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eran

Comment: new HashMap(); java 5 or 6 , New hashmap<>(); Java 7 onwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Java 7 diamond operator:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
```

Diamond <> allows the compiler to infer types implicitly

See: [Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)