# Is there a way to initialize a SortedMap<Integer, String> with values already included in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, initialization, sortedmap

I'd like to do something like so

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> stuff = new TreeMap<Integer, String>({1:"a",2:"b"});
```

much like you would do in python but is that possible in Java, or is the only way to call .put() twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting Java 9, you could do:

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> stuff = new TreeMap<>(Map.of(1, "a", 2, "b"));
```

Javadoc links:

[`TreeMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m)`](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Map))

[`Map<K, V> of(K k1, V v1, K k2, V v2)`](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V))

Comment: Ah, I'm on Java 8 so I guess I'll have to do it the old fashioned way

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the reasons devs upgrade their Java these days ;) Otherwise, you could use Guava's ImmutableSortedMap: https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap.html, but therefore need to add a third-party library.

Comment: Note that if you're wanting a Map that is sorted by *insertion* order (not natural sorting order), then you want a `LinkedHashMap`. And you can't use `Map.of` to construct it (because it doesn't maintain insertion order), so you need to construct it then use `.put` to add each value.

Answer (score 2):

The following holds true according to the Javadoc of `SortedMap` from both [Java-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) and [Java-14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html). It reads for a `SortedMap` :

> The expected "standard" constructors for all sorted map
>   implementations are:
>
> 1. A void (no arguments) constructor, which creates an empty sorted map
>      sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys.
> 2. A constructor
>      with a single argument of type `Comparator`, which creates an empty
>      sorted map sorted according to the specified comparator.
> 3. A constructor
>      with a single argument of type `Map`, which creates a new map with the
>      same key-value mappings as its argument, sorted according to the keys'
>      natural ordering.
> 4. A constructor with a single argument of type
>      `SortedMap`, which creates a new sorted map with the same key-value
>      mappings and the same ordering as the input sorted map.

and on the basis of **(3)**, you can simply initialize a `SortedMap` implementation wrapping another `Map` initialization as a constructor argument. There are a lot of options in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802483/how-to-directly-initialize-a-hashmap-in-a-literal-way) that match with other suggestions here.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

```
Stream.of(new SimpleEntry<>(1, "a"), new SimpleEntry<>(2, "b"))
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
            (a, b) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(); },
            TreeMap::new);
```

(Yuk).

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by M Anouti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61807319/10819573) holds good for only up to 10 entries. If you want to do it for more than 10 entries, you need to use `Map.ofEntries(Map.entry(k, v), Map.entry(k, v) ...)` as shown below:

```
import static java.util.Map.entry;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortedMap<Integer, String> stuff = new TreeMap<>(
                Map.ofEntries(entry(1, "a"), entry(2, "b"), entry(3, "c"), entry(4, "d"), entry(5, "e"), entry(6, "f"),
                        entry(7, "g"), entry(8, "h"), entry(9, "i"), entry(10, "j"), entry(11, "k"), entry(12, "l")));
        System.out.println(stuff);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{1=a, 2=b, 3=c, 4=d, 5=e, 6=f, 7=g, 8=h, 9=i, 10=j, 11=k, 12=l}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's double brace initializers:

```
Map stuff = new TreeMap<Integer, String>() {{
    put(1, "a");
    put(2, "b");
}};
System.out.println(stuff);
```

You can write this in one line if you want.

Although, I do not recommend this. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization).

Comment: Nobody should be initializing a map like this :) Not worth the readability benefit.

Comment: @MAnouti, yes. I did mention that. But it provides a way to call put twice. The linked answer is more than enough to explain why this should not be used.

Comment: @MAnouti actually, it doesn’t even have a readability benefit. There’s no significant difference to `Map<Integer, String> stuff = new TreeMap<>(); stuff.put(1, "a"); stuff.put(2, "b");` and since the double brace construct is creating a subclass, you have to repeat the type parameters in Java 8, which makes the double brace construct even longer…