# How to create a MutableMap with all keys initially set to same value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections, initialization, mutablemap

I want to create a mutable map whose keys fall in a continuous range, and values initially set to the same value 9 in a single line using Kotlin. How to do that?

Comment: Can you add an example map? If it's keys, there can only be one unique key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following way:

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val a :Int = 0
    val b :Int = 7
    val myMap = mutableMapOf<IntRange, Int>()
    myMap[a..b] = 9
    myMap.toMap()
    println(myMap) //Output: {0..7=9}

}
```

Comment: val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap<String, String>()
        params.put("1", "A")
        params.put("2", "B")

Answer (score 2):

One more option not mentioned in the other answers is to use the `associate*` function that takes the argument collection that it will put the pairs to:

```kotlin
val result = (1..9).associateWithTo(mutableMapOf()) { 9 }
```

Unlike `.associateWith { ... }.toMutableMap()`, this doesn't copy the collection.

If you need to use a different implementation (e.g. a `HashMap()`), you can pass it to this function, like `.associateWithTo(HashMap()) { ... }`.

Many collection processing functions in the Kotlin standard library follow this pattern and have a counterpart with an additional parameter accepting the collection where the results will be put. For example: `map` and `mapTo`, `filter` and `filterTo`, `associate` and `associateTo`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean values, you can use the `withDefault` function on any Map / MutableMap:

[(Playground)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS42LjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgdmFsIG1hcCA9IG11dGFibGVNYXBPZjxTdHJpbmcsIEludD4oKS53aXRoRGVmYXVsdCB7IDkgfVxuICAgIFxuICAgIG1hcFtcImhlbGxvXCJdID0gNVxuICAgIFxuICAgIHByaW50bG4obWFwLmdldFZhbHVlKFwiaGVsbG9cIikpXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihtYXAuZ2V0VmFsdWUoXCJ0ZXN0XCIpKVxufSJ9)

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>().withDefault { 9 }
    
    map["hello"] = 5
    
    println(map.getValue("hello"))
    println(map.getValue("test"))
}
```

Comment: Note that `withDefault { }` won't set a value into the original map.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
val map = object : HashMap<Int, Int>() {
    init {
        (1..10).forEach {
            put(it, 9)
        }
    }
}
println(map)
```

Comment: Note that this solution might have unexpected side effects: it creates a new class extending `HashMap`, which might not be desirable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802502/2196460 and https://wiki.c2.com/?DoubleBraceInitialization

Answer (score 1):

I would use *associateWith:*

```
val map = (1..9).associateWith { 9 }.toMutableMap()

println(map)   // {1=9, 2=9, 3=9, 4=9, 5=9, 6=9, 7=9, 8=9, 9=9}
```

It also works with other types as key, like *Char:*

```
val map = ('a'..'z').associateWith { 9 }.toMutableMap()

println(map)   // {a=9, b=9, c=9, d=9, e=9, f=9, g=9, h=9, i=9}
```