# What is the use of Map.ofEntries() instead of Map.of()

Tags: java, hashmap, java-9

From the documentation of [Map.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#immutable) -

> The `Map.of()` and `Map.ofEntries()` static factory methods provide a convenient way to create immutable maps.

But when I already can [use overloaded method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918934/what-is-the-point-of-overloaded-convenience-factory-methods-for-collections-in-j) ...

```
Map.of("k1","v1","k2","v2","k3","v3"...);
```

... what is the use of Map.ofEntries which also

> returns an immutable map containing keys and values extracted from the given entries and the entries themselves are not stored in the map.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

#### Any guesses on how would you create a Map of 26 elements?

The primary difference between the two factory methods in Map that you already linked is that :

**[`Map.ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-)**

> Returns an immutable map containing keys and values extracted from the
>   given **entries** (that are not bounded in count)

From the *[JEP-269:Convenience Factory Methods for Collections](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269)*:

> For larger numbers of entries, an API will be provided that will
>   create a Map instance given an **arbitrary number of key-value pairs**:
>
> ```
> Map.ofEntries(Map.Entry<K,V>...)
> ```
>
> While this approach is analogous to the equivalent varargs APIs for
>   List and Set, it unfortunately requires that each key-value pair be
>   boxed. A method for boxing keys and values, suitable for static
>   import, will make this more convenient:
>
> ```
> Map.Entry<K,V> entry(K k, V v)
> ```

---

Your assumption about the method `.of()` from Map is somewhat incorrect probably because while this would compile with Java9:

```
List<Integer> values = List.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10); // note 11 elements here

Set<String> keys = Set.of("z", "o", "tw", "th", "fo", "fi", "si", "se", "e", "n", "te");
```

This, on the other hand, wouldn't:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("z", 0, "o", 1,
      "tw", 2, "th", 3, "fo", 4, "fi", 5,
      "si", 6, "se", 7, "e", 8, "n", 9, "te", 10); // this would not compile
```

The reason for that is since there is a [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) implementation for **[`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-)** and **[`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#of-E...-)** but to create a similar API for `Map` both the keys and values were supposed to be boxed as stated in the JEP as well. So, the same was created using varargs of type **[`Map.entry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-)** as:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.ofEntries(Map.entry("z",0),
       Map.entry("o",1),Map.entry("t",2)...so on);
```

---

Furthermore from the documentation of `Map.entry()` which is also introduced *Since:9* -

> Returns an immutable `Map.Entry` containing the given key and value.
>   These entries are suitable for populating Map instances using the
>   `Map.ofEntries()` method.
>
> The `Entry` instances created by this method
>   have the following characteristics:
>
> - They disallow null keys and values. Attempts to create them using a null key or value result in NullPointerException.
> - They are immutable. Calls to Entry.setValue() on a returned Entry result in UnsupportedOperationException.
> - They are not serializable.
> - They are value-based. Callers should make no assumptions about the identity of the returned instances. This method is free to create new
>     instances or reuse existing ones. Therefore, identity-sensitive
>     operations on these instances (reference equality (==), identity hash
>     code, and synchronization) are unreliable and should be avoided.

which are similar to the characteristics of *[Immutable Map Static Factory Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#immutable)* introduced recently.

Answer (score 15):

Java 9 introduced creating small unmodifiable Collection instances using a concise one line code, for maps the signature of factory method is:

```
static <K,V> Map<K,V> of(K k1, V v1, K k2, V v2, K k3, V v3)
```

This method is overloaded to have 0 to 10 key-value pairs, e.g.

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("1", "first");
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("1", "first", "2", "second");
Map<String, String> map = Map.of("1", "first", "2", "second", "3", "third");
```

Similarly you can have up to ten entries.

For a case where we have more than 10 key-value pairs, there is a different method:

```
static <K,V> Map<K,V> ofEntries(Map.Entry<? extends K,? extends V>... entries)
```

Here is the usage.

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.ofEntries(
  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("1", "first"),
  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("2", "second"),
  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("3", "third"));
```

Comment: With that link seems like a spam. I don't find much of a difference from what has already been answered here and linked in the docs already.

Comment: *Additional note about the last part:* I would recommend using `Map.entry(k, v)` instead of `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(k, v)`, though (also available since JDK 9). Considerably more concise.

Comment: This is the most direct and easy-to-understand answer.

Answer (score 14):

Well it's very simple. `Map.of()` is not a varargs method. There are only overloaded `Map.of()` for up to 10 entries. On the other hand, `Map.ofEntries()` is a varargs method, hence allowing you to specify as many entries as you want.

They could have just added `Map.ofEntries()` but since many times you only need just a few entries, they also included the `Map.of()` versions as convenience methods so that you don't need to wrap each key-valur pair inside an `Entry`.

Comment: why isn't there a varargs version of `Map.of()`?

Comment: @ user5047085 — The key and value can be of different types.  There's no way in Java to represent a vararg enforcing that the odd elements be of type `K` and the even elements be of type `V`.  `ofEntries` gets around this as all the elements are of type `Entry<K, V>` (or more accurately, `Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>` to allow subyptes of `Entry<K, V>`).