# Initialize Map<String, Object> instance from Map entries

Tags: java, hashmap, java-10

Say I have some map entries like so:

```
var a = Map.entry("a", new Object());
var b = Map.entry("b", new Object());
var c = Map.entry("c", new Object());

var m = Map.of(a,b,c);  // error here
```

I get this error:

> Cannot resolve method
>   'of(java.util.Map.Entry,
>   java.util.Map.Entry,
>   java.util.Map.Entry)'

I just want to make a new Map from entries in a map, how can I do this?
Not the question is specifically about how to init a Map given Map.Entry instances.

Comment: I think Map.ofEntries will suffice. Suprising that Map.of is not overloaded to support entries, but I guess I know why.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen it is Java version 11, the var keyword was introduced, please

Comment: Actually it goes back to Java version 10, not 11, so..

Comment: more precisely `java-9`

Comment: @rakim from a [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601978/1746118) ... *The reason for that is since there is a varargs implementation for `List.of` and `Set.of` but to **create a similar API for Map both the keys and values were supposed to be boxed** as stated in the JEP as well. So, the same was created using varargs of type Map.entry()*... aside: have updated the tag to java-9 instead

Comment: @CommonMan The `var` keyword was introduced in Java 10 not Java 9.

Comment: You're lucky you passed an odd number of arguments to `Map.of`. If you had passed an even number of arguments, `m` would have been a map of entry to entry, specifically, `Map<Map.Entry<String,Object>,Map.Entry<String,Object>>`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace

```
Map.of(a,b,c);
```

with

```
Map.ofEntries(a,b,c);
```

---

If you want to still use `Map.of()` then you shall paste keys and values explicitly.

> `Map.Entry()` returns an immutable `Map.Entry` containing the given
>   key and value. These entries are suitable for populating Map instances
>   using the  `Map.ofEntries()` method.

[When to use `Map.of()` and when to use `Map.ofEntries()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601959/what-is-the-use-of-map-ofentries-instead-of-map-of)

Answer (score 4):

From jdk-9 you can use `Map.of()` to create `Map` with key value pairs

```
Map<String, Object> map = Map.of("a", new Object(), "b", new Object(), "c", new Object());
```

And also by using `SimpleEntry`

```
Map<String, Object> map = Map.ofEntries(
  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("a", new Object()),
  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("b", new Object()),
  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("c", new Object()));
```

Or by using `Map.ofEntries` OP suggestion

Comment: Map.ofEntries was what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is:

```
var a = Map.entry("a", new Object());
var b = Map.entry("b", new Object());
var c = Map.entry("c", new Object());

var m = Map.ofEntries(a,b,c);  // ! use Map.ofEntries not Map.of
```

And the type of `Map.entry(key,val)` is `Map.Entry<K,V>`, in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
var m = Map.ofEntries(a, b, c);
```

instead of

```
var m = Map.of(a,b,c);
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a map from entries Use either:

```
var a = Map.entry("a", new Object());
var b = Map.entry("b", new Object());
var c = Map.entry("c", new Object());

var m = Map.ofEntries(a,b,c);
```

or:

```
var m = Map.ofEntries(
             entry("a", new Object()),
             entry("b", new Object()),
             entry("c", new Object()));
```

---

You can also create the map without explicitly creating the entries:

```
var m = Map.of("a", new Object(),
               "b", new Object(),
               "c", new Object());
```