# Java 11 immutable map: create Map.Entry

Tags: java, java-11

In Java 11 there is a set of static methods in `java.util.Map` that allow instantiation of `AbstractImmutableMap`:

```java
static <K, V> Map<K, V> of(K k1, V v1) { return new Map1(k1, v1); }
static <K, V> Map<K, V> of(K k1, V v1, K k2, V v2) { return new MapN(new Object[]{k1, v1, k2, v2}); }
// ... some more "vararg" static methods until 10 pairs (inclusive).
```

There's also another method, that does almost the same, except it is true-vararg:

```java
static <K, V> Map<K, V> ofEntries(Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>... entries) { /* impl here */ }
```

I want to use the latter method, as it allows to expand number of entries far past ten. The problem is, I don't know how to create `Map.Entry`. It has a lot of implementations in different `Map`s, but there is no `new` operator or static fabric method for it, whereas `Map` has it.

`Map#ofEntries` is also used internally in `Map#copyOf`, but I cannot find a way to use it without already existing `Map` implementation with some entries in it. :/

I've tried searching for it, but couldn't find an answer.

➥ So, my question is: how was it intended to use `Map#ofEntries`? Or there is a way to instantiate `Map.Entry` without writing my own implementation or using anonymous classes?

Comment: Related to [What is the use of Map.ofEntries() instead of Map.of()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601959/what-is-the-use-of-map-ofentries-instead-of-map-of)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `static` [`Map#entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) method to create a single, unmodifiable instance of `Map.Entry`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.ofEntries(Map.entry("One", 1), Map.entry("Two", 2));
```

Printing `map` can result in the following output:

```
{One=1, Two=2}
```

Comment: I can't believe I was that blind! Thanks! Probably I've looked for `Map.Entry#of`, instead of much simpler `Map#entry`. :D

Comment: (You might also want to use `import static` to make it a bit shorter.)