# How to initialize HashSet values by construction for Double?

Tags: java

I am following link : [How to initialize HashSet values by construction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041778/how-to-initialize-hashset-values-by-construction?newreg=dcfb635715de40c4aee35a851fc103fd) and could be very silly question to ask, but I didn't make it working, please guide.

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Double> tempSet = new HashSet<Double>();
        tempSet.add(11.0);
        tempSet.add(22.0);

        // Below both lines not working
        Set<Double> tempSet1 = new HashSet<Double>({11.0, 22.0});
        Set<Double> tempSet1 = new HashSet<Double>(){11.0, 22.0};
    }
}
```

Comment: `Set<Double> tempSet1 = new HashSet<Double>({11.0, 22.0});` doesn't compile. What kind of initialization are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in one line of code?

Answer (score 1):

This statement doesn't make any sense: `Set<Double> tempSet1 = new HashSet<Double>({11.0, 22.0});` If you're trying to initiallize them in just one line of code try this: `Set<String> h = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Double[] {11.0,22.0}));`
Select as answer if it works! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 9, Then

```
Set<Double> dblSet5 = Set.of(11.20, 2.0, 32.0, 56.0);
```

**Or**

```
Set<Double> dblSet5 = Set.of(<Array Of Double>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Double> tempSet1 = new Hashset<Double>(Arrays.asList(11.0,22.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2041778/1065197), here are some examples:

```
//List initialization by using an array
Set<Double> h = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(11.0, 22.0));
//Java 8
Set<Double> set = Stream.of(11.0, 22.0).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```