# Is there a way to refactor a Set initialization to use Set.of() using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9

Is there a way to refactor this in IntelliJ (or even with Eclipse), to transform the first script to the second one :

Set initialization before Java 9 :

```
Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();
values.add("a");
values.add("b");
```

Set initialization starting from Java 9 (creates an immutable set) :

```
Set<String> values = Set.of("a", "b");
```

Comment: You might have been happier to have found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041778/how-to-initialize-hashset-values-by-construction) before the current code implementation you've shared. The standard operations do not provide an option to refactor such code at present. On the contrary, I don't even see the usefulness in performing such task for a user, given that the characteristics of the two `Set`(`new HashSet` Vs `Set.of`) differ significantly.

Comment: Do note a possibility of `Set<String> values = new HashSet<>(); values.add("a"); values.add("b"); System.out.println(values);//consumed values.add("c"); //modified System.out.println(values);//consumed`, how would you expect this to be refactored?

Comment: I understand that there are differences between both codes (modifiable vs unmodifiable). But I think that by laziness, some developers won't bother with wrapping the Set with `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`

Comment: I wish I could use the same syntax available in Python (_set / frozenset_), like described in [Sets in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sets-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

The refactoring option may not be available in all the cases (the source set should be unmodifiable).

However IntelliJ has [inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html) that may be more suitable to detect such a case.

See under **Java > Java language level migration aids > Java 9** : **Immutable collection creation can be replaced with collection factory call** :

> This inspection helps to convert unmodifiable collections created
>   before Java 9 to new collection factory methods like `List.of` or
>   `Set.of`. Also since Java 10 the conversion to `List.copyOf`, etc. could
>   be suggested.
>
> Note that Java 9 collection factory methods do not
>   accept null values. Also set elements and map keys are required to be
>   different. It's not always possible to statically check whether
>   original elements are different and not null. Using the checkbox you
>   may enforce the inspection to warn only if original elements are
>   compile-time constants, so the conversion is guaranteed to be correct.
>
> This inspection is available since Java 9 only.
>   *New in 2017.2*

This inspection can be tested with this code :

```
Set<String> stringSet = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
```